# React native picker, not displaying on page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to `import` my picker.

```
// picker.android.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { StyleSheet, Picker } from "react-native";

const PickerList = props => {
  const { label, options, selectedValue, name, onChange, identifier } = props;
  return (

    <Picker
      selectedValue={selectedValue}
      onValueChange={onChange}
    >
      <Picker.Item
        key={"unselectable"}
        label={"Please select an option"}
        value=""
      />
      {options.map((option, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={option.id} label={option.label} value={option.id} />;
      })}
    </Picker>

  );
};

export default PickerList;
```

By using:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicator,
    ImageBackground,
    AsyncStorage,
    Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import {
    setYear,
    setStudent,
    setGroup,
    setCredentials,
    resetForm
} from "../actions/events";


import PickerList from "./common/Picker";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: ""
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hideElement: false };
        this.onLayout = this.onLayout.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onParentChange = this.onParentChange.bind(this);
        this.onGroupChange = this.onGroupChange.bind(this);
        this.onStudentChange = this.onStudentChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    onParentChange(e) {
        this.props.resetForm();
        this.props.setYear(e);
    }

    onGroupChange(e) {
        if (e !== "") {
            const {
                credentials: { year },
                categories
            } = this.props;
            this.props.setGroup(e, categories, year);
        }
    }

    onStudentChange(e) {
        if (e !== "") {
            this.props.setStudent(e);
        }
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(
            "loggedIn",
            JSON.stringify(this.props.credentials)
        );
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Month");
    }

    onLayout(e) {
        const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

        if (width > height) {
            this.setState({ hideElement: true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ hideElement: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            isLoading,
            categories,
            hasErrored,
            isLoadingCredentials,
            credentials: { year, group, student, showStudent }
        } = this.props;

        return (
                <View
                    style={styles.container}
                    onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}
                >
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>

                        <PickerList
                            selectedValue={year}
                            label="Year"
                            onChange={this.onParentChange}
                            options={categories}
                            style={styles.picker}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        categories: state.fetchCategories,
        isLoading: state.isLoading,
        hasErrored: state.hasErrored,
        credentials: state.setCredentials,
        isLoadingCredentials: state.isLoadingCredentials
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    isLoadingCredentials: loadingCredentials =>
        dispatch(isLoadingCredentials(loadingCredentials)),
    setCredentials: credentials => dispatch(setCredentials(credentials)),
    setYear: year => dispatch(setYear(year)),
    setGroup: (group, categories, year) =>
        dispatch(setGroup(group, categories, year)),
    setStudent: student => dispatch(setStudent(student)),
    resetForm: () => dispatch(resetForm())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        display: "flex",
        marginTop: 25
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#800080",
        padding: 10
    },
    picker: {
        width: 300,
        height: 30
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: "white"
    },
    logo: {
        flex: 1,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: "contain"
    }
});

                            />
```

I cannot get my picker to display, the props are there, but my picker wont display, when I debug the props I get reference errors:

**ReferenceError: s is not defined at eval (eval at  
ReferenceError: t is not defined at eval**

Any ideas why this is happening? How can I display my `Picker`?

**UPDATE:**

I can map the options and display them, its when I put the `Picker` in the `jsx` it doesn't display:

```
// this works
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Picker, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";

const PickerList = props => {
  const { label, options, selectedValue, name, onChange, identifier } = props;
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <View>
      {options.map((option, i) => {
        console.log(option);
        return <Text key={option.id}>{option.label}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PickerList;
```

Comment: If you are using expo generate a snack!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put some height and width on your picker:

```
 <Picker
   selectedValue={selectedValue}
   onValueChange={onChange}
   style={{ height: 200, width: 400 }}
 >
   ...
 </Picker>
```